# Convert Android application from one language to another

Tags: android, database, encryption, apk

I need to *convert* my  android app from **English** Language into **Arabic** Language, 
but the database inside the APK is encrypted.

Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should add new string in value with new name ex:
Strings-en.xml
Strings-ar.xml
and translate all value in your string file